# org.junit cant' be resolved in IntelliJ

Tags: android, junit, intellij-idea, actionbarsherlock, junit4

I wanna compile ActionBarSherlock in IntelliJ as a library module for my project, but the imports `import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.equalTo;`, `import static org.junit.Assert.assertThat;` and `import org.junit.Test;` can't be resolved.

Any ideas how to fix it?

Edit: When I uncomment the `ManifestParsingTest.java` in `ActionBarSherlock` and try to compile my project I get these:

```
Android Dex: [MoneyTracker] UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
[...]
Android Dex: [MoneyTracker] 1 error; aborting
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solved it. `test.com.actionbarsherlock.internal` was defined as a source folder in the `ActionBarSherlock` module.

Comment: So what exactly did you do? Remove that folder? I'm still confused...

Comment: Deleting the folder fixed it for me.